# Why does the .NET 7 CLI ignore warnings on subsequent builds?

Tags: .net, command-line-interface, .net-7.0, dotnet-cli

I’m building a simple Blazor WebAssembly project with .NET 7, using only the CLI, not Visual Studio. I’m wondering why .NET doesn’t continue to report the warning you see on the first build: it highlights the warning only there, then it disappears from the others builds.

[image]

Comment: It probably only rebuilds projects that have changed. Try issuing a `dotnet clean` before each build.

Comment: A warning does not prevent a project from generating a .dll.  It won't recompile the same source file again, unless you clean first.